# Jenkins multi branch pipeline to create a pr in one repo upon a merge to master in another

Tags: jenkins

I have created a job with access to two repos, read access for A and write access for B. Upon a successful merge to master of a pr in repo A, I want a job to be triggered that adds the hash of the successful PR from repo A to repo B/file.yaml and creates a PR in repo B for this addition.

I understand the basic of getting the job to trigger based on a successful merge. I am stuck on how to get the job to change a yaml file and create a pr based on this change.

Answer (score 0):

Once your second build triggers, you have to do is checkout repo B. You probably also want to create a new branch (you can use git commands for all this) and append your hash to the file. The easiest way to do that is to echo the line:

```
sh "echo $COMMIT_HASH >> file.yaml"
```

Then push the code to your branch. Once the code is in the branch, you can create the PR, but how you do this depends on your Git host. Most popular hosts (Bitbucket, GitLab, GitHub) have API endpoints you can send POST requests to with the branch name. When the API gets the request, a PR is created. For example, this is how you do it with Bitbucket: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pullrequests/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-pullrequests-post.

If you are using a somewhat obscure Git host that doesn't have an API then you might be in a bit of trouble.

Comment: What commands would be used to do this? That's what I am having the most difficulty obtaining. For example, I'm unsure what parameters to set for the git () command so that a new branch is created after checking out into repoB/path/to/file.yaml. Would I just use shell? I was trying to stick to the declarative pipeline commands.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do things like creating and pushing branches with the declarative commands, so you may have to use regular git commands for this with shell.